# How does feign obtain header data for the requested interface

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am requesting an interface with [feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) and need to get the `Headers` value  for that interface.

I have used [feign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign) for the requested interface headers transfer parameters before, pass token to headers:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/get-store-list")
List<Store> getStoreList(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String Authorization);
```

However, this interface puts the amount of data in the `x-total-count` of headers, so I still need to get the value of `x-total-count`.
How do I get the value of `x-total-count`.

Comment: I do not quite understand the details. What do you mean by “this interface puts the amount of data […]”? Is the `X-Total-Count` header part of the answer of the call to the `/api/get-store-list`resource?

Comment: Page<Store> storePage = storeRepo.findAll(pageable); 
response.addHeader("X-Total-Count", storePage.getTotalElements() + "");
This stores the number of lists in "x-total-count"

Comment: And now you want to write an interface to use with Feign that will read that resource and extract its `X-Total-Count` header so you know in advance how much paged fetching is necessary?

Comment: Yes, the ultimate goal is to get the value of X-Total-Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feign has the headers in the `Response` object, and that can be the return value:

```java
public interface Swapi {
    @RequestLine("GET /people/{id}/")
    Response personResponse(@Param("id") int person);
}
```

Now you can call `headers()` on the result. That, of course, leaves you with the body as a string, which is not pretty. Let’s try something more Feign like.

---

```java
@Data
public class Person {
    String name;
    int height;
    int mass;
}

public interface Swapi {
    @RequestLine("GET /people/{id}/")
    Person person(@Param("id") int person);
}
```

Now the headers are hidden again, but they are still available to the decoder, which is the place that I will plug in:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HeaderReadingDecoder implements Decoder {

    private final Decoder wrappedDecoder;

    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
        var server = response.headers().getOrDefault("server",
            List.of("")).iterator().next();
        System.out.println("server = " + server);
        var etag = response.headers().getOrDefault("etag",
            List.of("")).iterator().next();
        System.out.println("etag = " + etag);
        return wrappedDecoder.decode(response, type);
    }
}
```

Of course, `System.out` is evil, but I really don’t know yet what you want to do with that header value. It’s up to you. Now you can use this with:

```java
Swapi swapi = Feign.builder()
    .decoder(new HeaderReadingDecoder(new JacksonDecoder()))
    .target(Swapi.class, "https://swapi.co/api");
Person person = swapi.person(2);
System.out.println("person = " + person);
```

And you will get:

```
server = cloudflare
etag = "3a58f420395ff0deed943e331d3bf74b"
person = Person(name=C-3PO, height=167, mass=75)
```

Comment: Well, @kangwenLiu , if it helped you enough, you may want to accept this answer as the correct one.

Comment: “Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.” ！！！ :(

Comment: I see. It’s been a long time since my first days, but I really thought there would be that greyed-out tick mark that could turn green. Later, perhaps.

Comment: It's ok now. I made a mistake

Comment: Hi...this is old thread but can we work this with contract with void return (no content) ? Because if I use "Response" in contract, instead of void, it does not go through error decoder.